# innerHTML not displaying float? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I scoured this site looking for someone who had a similar issue as me and I couldn't seem to find it. I'm really wracking my brain on this.

The point of the code is to take two inputs (Hourly rate and hours worked in a week) and output the amount earned in a year. I use innerHTML to grab those variables from forms and then add the two into a variable and try to use innerHTML again to put it into a paragraph. It keeps giving me "undefined". Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var rate = document.getElementById('hourlywage').value;
var parsedRate = parseFloat(rate);
var hours = document.getElementById('hoursworked').value;
var parseHours = parseFloat(hours);
var result = (parseRate * parseHours * 52.0);

function annualSal(){
document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = result ;
}

</script>

<h6>Hourly Wage:</h6>
<input type="text" id="hourlywage" />
<h6>Hours Per Week:</h6>
<input type="text" id="hoursworked" />
<h6><h6>
<button onclick="annualSal()">Click Here</button>
<p>The Hourly Rate is:</p>
<p id="outcome"></p>
```

Comment: You've misspelt parsedRate as parseRate. You are also trying to read the values before they've been entered, as well as trying to refer to elements on the page before they exist.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e0v5nc8f/

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple mistakes:

First one is misspelling a variable name.
Second one is that part of your JavaScript is being ran before your HTML elements being made so those elements don't exist yet when you refer to them.

Here is a fixed one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function annualSal(){
        var rate = document.getElementById('hourlywage').value;
        var parsedRate = parseFloat(rate);
        var hours = document.getElementById('hoursworked').value;
        var parseHours = parseFloat(hours);
        var result = (parsedRate * parseHours * 52.0);
        document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML = result;
    }
</script>
```

By moving the outside of function part of the code inside the function, it will be run each time you press the button, so on each run we are sure that elements like `hourlywage` and `hoursworked` do exist, it also re-gets the values on each time you run `annualSal` so if the user changes the values in the input boxes and clicks again on the button they will get updated results based on new values.

Comment: Even if he runs the code after the elements exist, it will run before the user has ever had a chance to type into them.

Comment: @Barmar: The codes are now inside `annualSal` function, so they will run when user clicks on the button that calls this function.